# PdfPageEventHelper with multiple elements

Tags: c#, itext

I need to add a logo and a header table to all pages of a pdf report generated with itextsharp. I am able to add the logo correctly, but not the header table.

Here is my code:

```
public class pdfPage : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
{           
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
        PdfPTable headerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);

        headerTbl.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;

        Image logo = Image.GetInstance("logo.png");

        logo.ScalePercent(42);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(logo);

        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

        cell.PaddingRight = 52;

        cell.Border = 0;

        headerTbl.AddCell(cell);

        headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (doc.PageSize.Height - 10), writer.DirectContent);

        PdfPTable headerrow = new PdfPTable(7);
        headerrow.TotalWidth = 570f;
        headerrow.LockedWidth = true;
        headerrow.AddCell(new Phrase("TIPO DOCUMENTO", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6f)));

        headerrow.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (doc.PageSize.Height - 50), writer.DirectContent);
    }
}
```

As I said the page event adds the "headerTbl" but not the "headerrow", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, using `OnStartPage` for adding content is a bad idea. You should use `OnEndPage` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're main problem line is:

```
PdfPTable headerrow = new PdfPTable(7);
```

You are trying to create a 7 column table but only adding a single cell to it. iTextSharp doesn't auto-complete missing cells for you by default. Change that to:

```
PdfPTable headerrow = new PdfPTable(1);
```

As @mkl said in the comments, however, you should also switch to `OnEndPage` instead of `OnStartPage`. Your code might work as-is right now but you could also run into infinite loops under certain conditions. [Direct from the source comments](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.cs#l72) say:

> Note that if even if a page is not written this method is still called. It is preferable to use `onEndPage` to avoid infinite loops.